Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Show that the only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$. (From Axler's book.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 17 in Exercises 3A on p.58 in this book.

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Show that the only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$.
A subspace $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is called a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ if $TE\in\mathcal{E}$ and $ET\in\mathcal{E}$ for all $E\in\mathcal{E}$ and all $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$.

My attempt:

Assume that $\mathcal{E}\neq\{0\}$.
Then, there exists $S\in\mathcal{E}$ such that $S\neq 0$.
$I$ is a linearly independent list in $\mathcal{L}(V)$.
Since $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is finite-dimensional, there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $I,S,S^2,\dots,S^n$ is a linearly dependent list in $\mathcal{L}(V)$.
So, there exist $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0I+a_1S+\dots+a_nS^n=0$.
Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a two-sided ideal, $a_1S+\dots+a_nS^n\in\mathcal{E}$.
So, $-a_0I=a_1S+\dots+a_nS^n\in\mathcal{E}$.
$\dots$

If I can show that $a_0\neq 0$, then $I\in\mathcal{E}$.
So, $T=TI\in\mathcal{E}$ for any $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$.
So, $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{L}(V)$.
Is it possible to complete my attempt?
By the way, I used $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is finite-dimensional in my attempt, but the proof of this fact is on p.87 in this book. So, I don't want to use this fact.

I don't think there is a way to complete your proof. For example, if $S$ happens to be a non-identity idempotent operator, meaning $S^2 = S$ but $S \neq I$, then you cannot have $aS + bS^2 = (a+b)S = cI$ for some nonzero $c$.
You can use the finite-dimensional condition of $V$ to realize $\mathcal{L}(V)$ as the ring of $\dim(V) \times \dim(V)$ matrices over the base field, which is also a vector space over the base field. So now $S$ is some non-zero matrix. The question is, using $S$, can you get every matrix or maybe just a set of matrices spanning all matrices? Here are two steps, each with a question to guide you and an answer if you get stuck.
Question 1:

 Can you come up with matrices $T$ and $U$ so that $TSU$ has only one nonzero entry?

Answer 1:

 $S$ has some nonzero entry, say in row $i$ and column $j$, which we denote as the $(i, j)$ entry. Let $T$ be the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,i)$ entry and zeros elsewhere, and $U$ be the matrix with $1$ in the $(j,j)$ entry and zeros elsewhere. Then $TSU$ equals to $S$ in the $(i,j)$ entry, but zero elsewhere.

Question 2:

 Let $E_{kl}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in $(k,l)$ entry and zeros elsewhere. The matrices $E_{kl}$ for $1 \leq k,l \leq \dim(V)$ span the space of $\dim(V) \times \dim(V)$ matrices. By multiplying matrices to $TSU$, can you get all the $E_{kl}$'s?

Answer 2:

 First, if the nonzero entry of $TSU$ equals $a$, then you can multiply $TSU$ by $a^{-1} I$ so that $a^{-1} I TSU = a^{-1} TSU$ has a single entry with $1$ and zeros everywhere else. Row and column swap matrix operations can be realized by multiplication by permutation matrices on the left/right, so by multiplying permutation matrices to $a^{-1} TSU$ you can get all the $E_{kl}$'s.


rso, Thank you very much for your very kind answer!
